# Entity Framework 1-to-1 insertions

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have a schema where one table has probably 6-7 1-to-(0..1) relationships. I split the table up because I would rather have an empty row in a table than a bunch of nulls in the other table.

Basically I have my Student entity return an Advisor entity that contains 5 strings holding the advisor name. If the student already has an advisor everything works fine, but if i try to add to the student an advisor or a new student the changes don't persist. I basically have a WPF window that has the student data and text boxes data bound to the student Advisor class. I assumed the problem with insertion was because the value of advisor is null if the record doesn't exists so I created a method that would set the student advisor to a new advisor class, but that still does not persists the changes.

I found this article http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/9b68f183-ba28-4a94-8c65-545611726268, but I want to know how I can do it and still keep my data bindings to the advisor text boxes.

Comment: Your question is very unclear.

Comment: Ok. A student is a table and it is in a 1-to-(0-1) relationship with another table named advisor. I currently have a student, but want to add an advisor to that student. On the WPF window I have textboxes for all the student data bound to the current student object I get from my view. I also have textboxes bound to the student's advisor class. However if the student doesn't already have a record in the advisor table the information won't get saved to the database. In the debugger the value for the advisor is null. I have tried instantiating an advisor class and it still doesn't work.